# Change onclick method in mvc submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, viewbag

I have a `submit` button where I want to change the onclick method based on `CurrentGroupName` And I bring `CurrentGroupName` from ViewBag.

So here is the code if

`CurrentGroupName` = O&M Fiber Engineer I want `onclick="return SaveFiberInfofttx('Approve');"` method to enable.

And if

`CurrentGroupName` = O&M Fiber Lead I want `onclick="return FiberLeadRejValidation_FTTX('Approve');"` method to enable.

Here is my button code.

```html
<input type="button" id="btnRemarksSubmitFLFTTX" class="button submit" value="@((ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Lead") ? Html.Raw("Accept") : Html.Raw("Approve"))">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the required button attributes within a separate code block in the following manner:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    //ViewBag.CurrentGroupName = "O&M Fiber Lead";
    ViewBag.CurrentGroupName = "O&M Fiber Engineer";
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{ 
    string buttonText = string.Empty;
    string onClickHandler = string.Empty;
    if (ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Lead") {
        buttonText = "Accept";
        onClickHandler = "return FiberLeadRejValidation_FTTX('Approve');";
    } else if (ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Engineer") {
        buttonText = "Approve";
        onClickHandler = "return SaveFiberInfofttx('Approve');";
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function FiberLeadRejValidation_FTTX(arg) {
    }
    function SaveFiberInfofttx(arg) {
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type="submit" value="@buttonText" onclick="@onClickHandler">
}
```

Comment: Let me check and update you accordingly..!!

Comment: Hi @Mikhail, there are two buttons one is for approve and another one is for reject, but even if I click on Reject button still I see Approve text on the reject button why is it so ? here is the html :- `<input type="button" class="button reject" value="@((ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Engineer" || ViewBag.CurrentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Lead") ? Html.Raw("Reject") : Html.Raw("Reject"))" onclick="return SaveFiberDatafttx('Reject');" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can using the following code:

```
@{
    string currentGroupName = ViewBag.CurrentGroupName;
    string onClickMethod = "";
    if (currentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Engineer")
    {
        onClickMethod = "return SaveFiberInfofttx('Approve');";
    }
    else if (currentGroupName == "O&M Fiber Lead")
    {
        onClickMethod = "return FiberLeadRejValidation_FTTX('Approve');";
    }
}
<button type="submit" onclick="@onClickMethod">Submit</button>
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the value of `ViewBag.CurrentGroupName` should match exactly with the value "O&M Fiber Lead" (including upper/lower case). If the value doesn't match, the button will display "Approve" instead of "Accept".

Comment: where can I write this code ? Is it just above the button html code ? or somewhere else

Comment: Yes, you can write the code just above the button HTML code in your Razor view. The code you provided should work fine in this case.